# How to check route parameter exists in layout page asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 parameters in url `id & text`. I am trying to check whether `'text'` exists in `layout page` because initially I will have only `Id` and later I am addding `'text'` to url from different action but same controller.

I have following code in my layout page but it works only when both parameters are available.

```
var Newid,Newtext;
  Newid = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
  Newtext = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["text"].ToString();
```

I am trying to check when my url is `localhost:8122/products/12`

```
@
{
if(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["text"].ToString()!=null)
{

}

}
```

but it gives object reference error.

I have to include `.tostring()` since I am checking like below in the same page

```
 @if (Newtext =="t") {}
```

Comment: Remove the `ToString();`

Comment: No it didnt solve that way .  I am checking some condition in layout page like  @if (Newtext == "t")

Comment: FGS. You first check if its `null` or not (and you need to remove the `.ToString()`. Then is its not `null`, you can test it as a `string`

Comment: My url will be , localhost:8122/product/12  and this time I am checking following in layout page @if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["text"].ToString() == "t") {} it gives error

Comment: Read the comments `if(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["text"] !=null && ViewContext.RouteData.Values["text"].ToString() == "t") { ... }`